# Problems with Kallithea and LDAP/ Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, ldap, kallithea

Trying to setup Kallithea and authentication with our Active Directory. Looked through the docs. for Kallithea-scm.org, but without succes.

I have entered the correct LDAP information for our AD according to the guide, but no users are "imported"

I have checked that python can make ldap searches with success.

Does anyone use Kallithea with AD support that may be able to assist me.?

Comment: Are the users able to log in? I've noticed on my Kallithea instance the users are only imported once they try to log in once.

Answer (score 0):

works fine for me. You need to install the `python-ldap` module. Then configure it as describes for active directory

see:
https://pythonhosted.org/Kallithea/setup.html